# Generate INSERT statement from SELECT query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, import

I have two databases, in first database I have a table called `zoom_city` and in the second database I have a table called `courrier_city`. The SQL for each is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zoom_city` (
  `id_ciudad` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `capital` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ciudad`),
  KEY `id_estado` (`id_estado`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=644;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courrier_city` (
  `country` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `capital` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deletedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country`,`state`,`id`),
  KEY `fk_courrier_city_state1_idx` (`country`,`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So I need to dump values from first table `zoom_city` and insert them in `courrier_city` but taking this in account:

- `country` always be `VE` string
- `id_estado` are stored in `zoom_city` as for example `1, 2, 3, 10` and right values for `courrier_city` and taking same example would be `VE.01`, `VE.02`, `VE.03` and `VE.10` so this value needs a transform before insertion.

Is that possible in raw SQL or I need to do this in a programming language like PHP for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't clear where you want the transformed id_estado inserted, so I chose "state" as a destionation.   You can modify accordingly:

```
insert into courrier_city (country, state, created, modified) select "VE", if(is_estado<10, concat("VE0.",is_estado),concat("VE.",is_estado)), now(), now() from zoom_city
```

You will probably want to modify the example further to account for specifying all the destination columns with either a literal value such we did for country, a transform like we did for is_estado, or just the basic column name in the select portion to copy values.

You should specify some value for every destination column without a schema default defined.

Comment: I modified a bit the query and now looks like `INSERT INTO courrier_city (country, state, created, modified) SELECT "VE", IF(id_estado<10, CONCAT("VE.0", id_estado),CONCAT("VE.", id_estado)), NOW(), NOW() FROM zoom_city` but I get this error any time I try to run it `[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry 'VE-VE.01-' for key 'PRIMARY'` why is that?

Comment: Because you ran it twice and already had a copy of your primary key tuple, which enforces uniqueness I'm guessing.  If you're doing a fresh run you can either truncate your destination table (I'll leave it to you if wiping everything out for a clean slate is appropriate), or look at the insert on duplicate key update syntax